# ASP.NET - Change variable with conditional operator

Tags: asp.net, forms, razor, sendmail, conditional-operator

Basically here is the main part of the code that contains the error:

```
...

var lname = Request["lastName"];
var comment = Request["comment"];
var sex = Request["sex"];
var title = "";

if(sex = "woman"){
    title = "Misses ";
} else {
    title = "Mister ";
}

...
```

When i run the site and submit the form it gives me the following Compiler Error Message: *CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool':*

Does anyone have a solution to this?
Every suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
if(sex == "woman")
```

And you can consider using ternary operator

```
title = (sex == "woman") ? "Misses" : "Mister";
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Can't say why I didn't notice the failure in declaration.